# SharePoint 2013 REST How to $filter field1 eq field2 (not field eq constantValue)?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, filter, field

Am I missing something or is it really impossible to use SharePoint REST API to filter a list based on the contents of a field and another field?

Constant values work:

```
?$select=Title&$filter=Title eq 'Hello world'
```

or

```
?$select=Title&$filter='Hello world' eq Title
```

but *not*

```
?$select=Title&$filter=Title eq Title
```

nor

```
?$select=Title&$filter=Title eq OtherField
```

nor

```
?$select=Title&$filter=substringof(Title, Title)
```

With filtering that limited, REST is practically useless.

Is there some way to use variables or refer to other fields?

**EDIT:**
I just checked, apparently it is a limitation in the SharePoint. 
It also does not work using CAML, apparently all comparisons have to be Field to ConstantValue.

Doesn't work either:

```
<Query>
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title" /><FieldRef Name="Title" /></Eq></Where>
</Query>
```

Any idea how to work around this issue? Lookups, Joins? In REST? Thanks.

Comment: Limitation in SharePoint? I have never seen a REST API do what you are asking. The obvious approach is to fetch the data you need and do the filtering with some filter function that you've written. Sure, it requires a few extra lines of code but it still requires only one API call.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it requires at least a Join to do such a thing. 
It just looks trivial from the context that I wanted to use it in (a custom field type that allows filtering based on some criteria, which unfortunately won't make a temporary fetch first).

Comment: Why a join? Just fetch the data in one call, then in your code you filter out the data where `Field1 == Field2` as you want to do in your question. Only if you want to fetch something where `List1.Field == List2.Field` you'll need to make at least two separate calls.

Answer (score 1):

only way that call two diffrent uri two times and then by using loop and variables in javascript do that action you need , like below code :

NEED EDIT FOR CALL

```
 $(function (){loadRequest("/_api//web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/PublishingImages/wodSlider')/files",
    function (data) {
        var wodsliderData = data.d.results;


        var viewXml = '<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FSObjType" /><Value Type="Integer">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>';
        var array2 = [];
        array2=getListItems(webUrl,listTitle,viewXml);


        var html='';
        if(wodsliderData.length!=0){
            for(i=0;i<wodsliderData.length;i++){
                for(j=0;j<array2.length;j++){
                //............. your code here
            }
            }
        }

        $('#wodSliderHtml').html(html);


    });
 });
 function getListItems(webUrl,listTitle, viewXml) 
{
var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems"; 
var queryPayload = {  
           'query' : {
                  '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                  'ViewXml' : viewXml
           }
};

return $.ajax({
       url: url,
       method: "POST",
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
       headers: {
          "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
          "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
       }
 });
}
```

Comment: even its best solution to work with Managed Metadata (Taxonomy) type.

Answer (score 0):

Use not equal to filter

```
https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/demo/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?&$filter=Title ne null
```